# Is it ok to add a second subscription to a pub/sub topic that triggers Firestore document changes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Firebase project.  I setup Google cloud function (2nd gen) that is triggered when a Firestore collection is created/updated/deleted.  I noticed that the function is connected to pub/sub subscription and when Firestore docs change, then this will push a message to a pub/sub topic which will trigger the cloud function.

I would like to know if it is save to add an additional subscription (with ordering) to this topic and have a pull subscriber pulls messages from this subscription.  Would that be allowed?  But if that is allowed, how would I know the name of the topic dynamically so that I can refer to it without hardcoding the topic name.  This is important because I have three different regions.

Comment: Why don't you just code the trigger to push another message into a different topic that you create yourself and fully control? Then you don't have to depend on undocumented implementation details.

Comment: I am doing that right now.  But I was hoping I can save money by not having to send the Firestore docs again into pub/sub.